# HOw remove Duplicate data from Array result of PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

i am getting PDO Query result in array . Query is changes dynamically. So don't write answer to change query. Query result is Fixed. Print_r display following result.

```
              while($r = $q->fetch())
```

Which stores on  $r  consist

```
  [number]       => 001 
  [code]        => 387
  [ACCOUNTTYPE]      => 60 

 [number] => 001 
 [code] => 387 
 [ACCOUNTTYPE] => 61 

 [number] => 002 
 [code] => 388
 [ACCOUNTTYPE] => 67 

 [number] => 002
 [code] => 388
 [ACCOUNTTYPE] => 65
```

and now it Display.

```
 001  | 387  | 60 |
 001  | 387  | 61 |
 002  | 388  | 67 |
 002  | 388  | 65 |
```

I want To Remove Duplicate entry and enter black data.

i want array like this or print to display in php table like this

```
 001  | 387  | 60 |
      |      | 61 |
 002  | 388  | 67 |
             | 65 |
```

So how can i do this.  So how i can Group this . Some times Group columns are more.

**$groupcolunmsarray**  consist which columns want to group.
Now its consisit value **number** and **code**

```
  $groupcolunmsarray[0]=number
  $groupcolunmsarray[1]=code
```

using  $groupcolunmsarray and $r how can i group and remove duplicate or order by like this Structure.

```
 001  | 387  | 60 |
      |      | 61 |
 002  | 388  | 67 |
             | 65 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is insufficient data so its  impossible & write in detail plz.
Use For loop and if condition to Remove repetitive data.